# If $M$ is p.d with $M^{-1}=\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}^{-1}=\pmatrix{P&Q\\R&S}$, then $P-A^{-1}$ is n.n.d.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

> Let $M$ be a real positive definite matrix such that $M^{-1}=\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}^{-1}=\pmatrix{P&Q\\R&S}$, where $A$ is a square matrix. Then show that $P-A^{-1}$ is non-negative definite.

As $M$ is p.d, it is invertible. As principal minors of $M$ should be positive we have,

$\det(A)>0$ and $\det(M)=\det(A)\det(D-CA^{-1}B)>0$ (assuming all matrices have orders so that $D-CA^{-1}B$ is square), thus implying $A$ and $D-CA^{-1}B$ are both invertible.

Now using the formula for inverse of block matrices,

$P=A^{-1}+A^{-1}BF^{-1}CA^{-1}$ where $F=D-CA^{-1}B$.

$\implies P-A^{-1}=A^{-1}BF^{-1}CA^{-1}$.

I don't see why this has to be n.n.d. Possibly I am missing something obvious.

Comment: This proof only works if positive definite implies symmetric.  Can we assume in this context that $M$ is meant to be a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Notably, the trick with the principal minors only works if $M$ is symmetric

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Can't we always take $M$ to be symmetric without loss of generality?

Comment: It depends on what exactly "without loss of generality" means in this context.  If you're using positive definite matrices to represent a quadratic form (or symmetric bilinear form), then it is indeed common to assume that $M$ is symmetric, without loss of generality.  However, different matrices that induce the same quadratic form can have drastically different properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is a symmetric matrix, then we have
$$
P-A^{-1}=A^{-1}BF^{-1}CA^{-1} = [A^{-1}B]F^{-1}[A^{-1}B]^T
$$
Since $F^{-1}$ is (symmetric and) positive definite, the matrix $QF^{-1}Q^T$ (where $Q = A^{-1}B$) must be (symmetric and) non-negative definite.

Comment: You seem to take $A$ to be symmetric. Is $A$ also p.d?

Comment: @StubbornAtom if $M$ is symmetric and p.d. then all of its principal submatrices are symmetric and p.d.

Comment: Doesn't this show that $P-A^{-1}$ is positive definite to be precise? Also, what would you recommend doing if $M$ is not symmetric?

Comment: We can only say that $P  - A^{-1}$ is positive definite (i.e. invertible) if we are given that $A^{-1}B$ is invertible, which notably can only happen if $B$ is square.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I don't think that the statement holds if we're not given that $M$ is symmetric

Comment: I made a mistake earlier: $P - A^{-1}$ might be invertible if $B$ has full row rank.

Answer (score 1):

the positive definite feature is defined for symmetric matrices in most texts. I guess for your problem too. In order M to be  symmetric $A$ and $D$ should be symmetric and you should have $C=B^T$.So you can write $M$ as follows:
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
B^T & D\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You should study Schur complement.The matrix M is positive definite if and only if the schur complement of $M$ relative to $A$ is positive definite. This schur complement is defined as follows:
$X/A=D-B^TA^{-1}B$
Since M is positive definite$X/A=D-B^TA^{-1}B$ is positive definie. Now it is easy to answer your question. as you have mentioned
$$P-A^{-1}=A^{-1}BF^{-1}CA^{-1}=A^{-1}BF^{-1}B^{T}A^{-1}$$ in which $F=D-CA^{-1}B=D-B^{T}A^{-1}B$ is positive definite. Here you should know that if a matrix is positive definite its inverse is positive definite too. So $F^{-1}$ is positive definite.Now consider the vector $x$. By  constituting quadratic form for $P-A^{-1}$ we have:
$$x^{T}(P-A^{-1})x=x^{T}A^{-1}BF^{-1}B^{T}A^{-1}x=(B^{T}A^{-1}x)^{T}F^{-1}(B^{T}A^{-1}x)\ge 0$$.The $\ge$ sign is written by using the positive definite property of $F^{-1}$ Take care that $A^{-1}$ is symmetric too.So $P-A^{-1}$ is positive semi-definite.